# Java crawler library - recursive HTTP subtree download with directory listing parser

Tags: java, http, web-crawler

My application currently reads data by copying filesystem tree from remote machine via shared disk, so it works as filesystem deep copy from application's point of view.

This solution is somewhat limiting and I want to support also second option - **copy subtree via http**.

The library should do something like `wget --recursive` which parses the directory listing and use it for traversing down the tree.

I could not find any java library doing this.

I am able to implement such functionality myself (with NekoHTML or something similar), but I don't like reinventing the wheel.

Is there such a **library** that I can *easily use* within my application ?

Ideally:

- published in Maven Central Repository as I am using Maven for builds
- with as few dependencies on other libraries as possible
- no need for robots exclusion support - will operate on limited set of interim servers only

Thanks.

*Note: please post pointers to homepages of libraries which you personally used.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Norconex HTTP Collector](http://www.norconex.com/product/collector-http/) traverses websites like a tree, given one or more start URLs.  It can be used as a java library in your application, or as a command line application.  You can decide what to do with each document it crawls. Being a full-blown web crawler, it probably does more than what you are after, but you can configure it to suit your need.

For instance, it will by default extract text found in your documents and it let's you decide what to do with that text via plugging a "Committer" (i.e. where to "commit" the extracted content). In your case I think you want to the raw documents only and ignore the text conversion part.  You can do so by plugging in your own document processor, followed by "filtering out" documents so they stop being processed once you have dealt with them your own way.

The project is open-source, hosted on Github and is fully "mavenized".  It supports robots.txt, but that can turn that off if you want.  The only downside to you is having more than a few dependencies, but since you are using Maven, those should get resolved automatically without effort.  You'll find [Maven repository info](http://www.norconex.com/product/collector-http/download.html) on the product site.

Comment: this looks like a very good direction, I will explore it - thanks!